# attempting a code challenge in js, getting unexpected results --

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming

The goal is to create a function called destroyer that filters all arguments after an initial array argument out of the array.

I'm not very good at functional programming yet so my answer doesn't work, but I'm getting some fish results that I don't understand.  Here's my function:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var count = 1;
  var result = arr;
  return result.reduce(function(val){
    if (count < arguments.length){
      console.log('count is ' + count);
      console.log("filtering " + arguments[count]);
       result = result.filter(function(val){val!=arguments[count]});
       count += 1;
       return result;

    }
    else {
      return result;
    }

  }, count);
}
```

Given `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);`, this evaluates to `[]`, whereas it should return [1, 1]

My console logs the following:

```
"count is 1"
"filtering 1"
"count is 2"
"filtering 1"
"count is 3"
"filtering 1,2,3,1,2,3"
```

What I don't understand:

1. Why is the conditional even evaluated when count is 3?  My if statement has `< arguments.length`(which is 3), not `<=`
2. Given the input `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);`, why isn't arguments[count] (which should be limited from 1 - 2) returning the console log "filtering 2" ... "filtering 3" ... (and nothing else... I have no clue why the last log is coming up).
3. About that last log... is it being returned because of arguments[3]?  Shouldn't that come up undefined?

Comment: You can instead do like `var destroyer = (a,...t) => a.filter(e => !t.includes(e));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you have a nested function inside a function and the value of the `arguments` object will be different inside both the closures.

I would suggest store each of them in a local variable and use instead of repeating the usage of `arguments`.

I did a dry run of your code in the console, and will attach a screenshot of the values of your `arguments` object and other variables for the first run for your understanding.

[image]

Notice how the value of `arguments` changes before and after the `return result.reduce(function(val)) {` line.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help you a bit.
1) arguments are 4, not 3. Add

```
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(arguments.length);
```

And you will see it yourself. First argument is acumulator for function reduce.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

```
    function destroyer(arr) {
      var count = 1;
      var result = arr;
      var args = arguments; //keep reference of original passed arguments;
      return result.reduce(function(val){
          //use args not arguments because here arguments 
          //will refer to the arguments of the inner function
        if (count < args.length){
          console.log('count is ' + count);
          console.log("filtering " + args[count]);
           result = result.filter(function(val){return val!=args[count]});
           count += 1;
           return result;

        }
        else {
          return result;
        }

      }, count);
    }

    destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```js
function removeAll(_arr, _rem)
{
  while(_arr.indexOf(_rem) !== -1)
  {
    var i = _arr.indexOf(_rem);
    _arr.splice(i,1);
  }
  return _arr;
}

function destroyer(_arr, _remA, _remB)
{
  var arr = removeAll(_arr, _remA);
  arr = removeAll(arr, _remB);
  return arr;
}

var arr = destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 2, 3);

console.log(arr);

document.getElementById('divOut').innerHTML = 'destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 2, 3) -> ' + JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<div id='divOut'></div>
```

though I would prefer to send an array of what to 'destroy' (/remove) as follows:

```js
    function removeAll(_arr, _rem)
    {
      while(_arr.indexOf(_rem) !== -1)
      {
        var i = _arr.indexOf(_rem);
        _arr.splice(i,1);
      }
      return _arr;
    }

    function destroyer(_arr, _remArray)
    {
      var arr = _arr.splice(0); // clone array
      for(var c = 0, length = _remArray.length; c < length; c++)
      {
        arr = removeAll(arr, _remArray[c]);
      }
      return arr;
    }

    var arr = destroyer([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,5]);

    console.log(arr);

    document.getElementById('divOut').innerHTML = 'destroyer([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,5]) -> ' + JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<div id="divOut"></div>
```